# Describing the path of a particle on a wheel that changes direction

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, experimental-mathematics

So I start with a particle rolling along the outside of a wheel. This can be constructed by setting up a vector function for a circle and adding a constant velocity to one component.

My wheel is going to be moving horizontally with a velocity v_0, so my vector is...
$$
\vec{s}=(r \cos t+v_{0}t)\hat{x}+r\sin t\hat{y}
$$

Now I want to implement a condition where the particle will 'bounce back' in the opposite direction once it has met a specific angle from the center. This step will change the path from looking like a flattened spring to a bent sine wave. Hopefully these pictures will help illustrate this.
[image]
[image]

The bottom function is a bit similar to the affect I am trying to achieve, but it is not circular. Anyway, is this just accomplished with a piece-wise function?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your $y$ period became twice longer. Don't change the period of the $y$ component and everything will be OK. Instead you should take negative velocity $v_0$ leaving the rest the same.

It looks also that your point moves counterclockwise when wheel moves forward. So you need to change $\sin t$ to $\sin(-t)$. When you point begin to move back you should change $\sin(-t)$ to $\sin t$ again.

Comment: I plotted this in segments (changing sin(t) to sin(-t) when appropriate). Here is the plot. (Pardon the odd coefficient choices- working with data). It doesn't look like the direction is changing, but I can not figure out why it wouldn't.




 


https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6kug5qzyyj

Comment: Could you, please, check with this settings: for the both curves $t\in [0,6\pi]$,for the first curve $x = r\cos t + vt, y = \sin -t$, for the second curve $x = -vt + r\cos t + (-r\cos 0 + 6\pi v + r \cos 6\pi),y = r\sin t/2$. Is that what you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for seems to be 
$$
\vec s=(r \cos(f(t))+v_0 t)\hat x+(r\sin(f(t)))\hat y   \tag1
$$
where $f(t)$ is a triangle wave function. 
You can get formulas for such functions from various sources such as [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleWave.html),
[this](http://planetmath.org/triangularwavefunction),
or others you can find by searching for "triangle wave function".

One way to write a triangle wave function is
$$
f(x) = {(-1)^{\lfloor t/P+1/2\rfloor}}2A
       \left(\frac tP - \left\lfloor \frac tP + \frac12\right\rfloor \right)
$$
where $A$ is the amplitude and $P$ is the period of the function.
The function will oscillate between the values $-A$ and $A.$
If $P=2A$ then $f(x)$ has slope $1$ or $-1$ when its slope is defined, which seems to be what you want. 
Substitute this for $f(t)$ in Equation $1$
and see what you get as a result.